# How to insert the data by splitting the string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert

I have been doing some learning on the SQL server.
So i got a task for myself.
I want to insert data into the table but with quite different input.

I have a table like

```
Technology_ID  | Technology_Name         
---------------|------------------     
             1 | C#,ReactJS
```

But I want like

```
Technology_ID  | Technology_Name                               
---------------|------------------                                                       
             1 | C#      
             2 | ReactJS
```

How Can I do this?

I tried something like this

```
WHILE CHARINDEX(',',@TechnologyList)>0
INSERT INTO Technology ([Technology_Name]) values (@TechnologyList)
```

How can I archive this?

Comment: What SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: I am working with SSMS 18

Comment: We need to know the version of the database engine.  SQL Server 2016 on should have the `STRING_SPLIT` function but we have no way of know if you can use that.  In the object explorer the version should be in parenthesis next to the server name.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `STRING_SPLIT()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` functions, you can see the script below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Technology (Technology_ID int, Technology_Name varchar(200))

INSERT INTO #Technology VALUES (1, 'C#,ReactJS')

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value) AS Technology_ID,
    Value AS Technology_Name
FROM
    STRING_SPLIT((SELECT Technology_Name FROM #Technology),',')
```

Documentation: [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or above, you can use `String_split` and `Cross Apply` to get the desired result.

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Technology_ID  varchar(100), Technology_Name varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @t SELECT '<<<<<<<<<< 1', 'C#,ReactJS'

SELECT * FROM @t t  
    
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t.Technology_ID) AS rn,
       value
FROM @t t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Technology_Name, ',') AS ss
)
SELECT rn AS Technology_ID, value AS Technology_Name FROM  cte c
```